# Pandas 'shift' moving value to completely different location

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I am attempting to shift a single column within a larger dataframe down by one row using Pandas, then add that shifted column to the original dataframe. Many of the values happen to be repeated in the problem I'm trying to solve:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})
```

Output:

```
    col1
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   2.0
4   2.0
5   2.0
6   2.0
7   3.0
8   4.0
```

Using

```py
    col_copy = df[['col1']]
    shift_col_copy = col_copy.shift(1, fill_value=0)
    df['newcol'] = shift_col_copy
```

I expect to see

```
    col1 newcol
0   1.0 0.0
1   1.0 1.0
2   1.0 1.0
3   2.0 1.0
4   2.0 2.0
5   2.0 2.0
6   2.0 2.0
7   3.0 2.0
8   4.0 3.0
```

However, what I am seeing instead is something similar to

```
    col1 newcol
0   1.0 0.0
1   1.0 1.0
2   1.0 1.0
3   2.0 2.0
4   2.0 2.0
5   2.0 2.0
6   2.0 2.0
7   3.0 1.0
8   4.0 3.0
```

that is, one of the values from the original column is missing in the shifted column, then reappears much later in the column. In my original dataframe, a value that *should* be repeated 16 times in the shifted column is instead only repeated 15 times; that missing value then reappears later, paired with a value from col1 that only appears once.

The code used above works perfectly when used in isolation, but when this code is used (within a function) to act on a larger dataframe, it produces the issues outlined.

**EDIT FOR ADDITIONAL INFO**
The reason I am doing this is to find the difference between a column value and the next column value. I learned I can do this with

```py
    df['newcol'] = df['col1'].diff()
```

but this also does not accurately produce the expected result around the same spot as the original error. The whole column is *float* datatype, but I am thinking something is wrong with the format of the numbers(?)...

Comment: `df['new_col'] = df['col1'].shift(fill_value=0)`

Comment: The error is still there. This was the first line of code I tried, but using '-1' as the shift argument; I changed to the version posted because I thought there was an error in the one-line version.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by Chris gives you correct answer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})
df['newcol'] = df.shift(fill_value=0)
```